# How can I overwrite, not merge, one remote branch into another branch?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have two branches. Staging and Beta. Staging has code in it ( including files ), that I do not want at all. How can I make Beta completely overwrite Staging, so that none of those files or code are merged from Staging into Beta.

I see some people recommend doing this :

```
git checkout staging
git merge -s ours beta
```

But I don't believe the pre-existing files would be a "code conflict" and therefore would not be removed. Am I wrong? If I'm right, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Is `staging` ahead from `beta` ? What is exactly the relationship between your two branches ?

Comment: They both have some data that is ahead. But I don't want anything on Staging.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can simple delete `staging` and re-create it based on `beta`:

```
git branch -D staging
git checkout beta
git branch staging
```

Comment: I thought about this too, but we have not enough information about the branches. I assume that the OP would not have asked this question if he only had to remove his branch

Comment: @Rerito: I disagree. Sometimes people just don't see the simple solution.

Comment: Removing the branch would destroy its history though?

Comment: @Trip: Yes. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Where did Trip say they wanted the history deleted?

Comment: @Amber: Nowhere. Did I say he did? No. But I inferred it from "Staging has code in it (including files), that I do not want at all". If he is not interested in the files in staging, what use is the history that lead to those files?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth shouldn't the last git branch need a '-b' option?

Comment: @MaxP: `-b` is not a valid option on `git branch`. [Source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)

Answer (score 25):

**If you don't care** about the old history of `staging`, you can just recreate it:

```
git checkout beta
git branch -f staging
```

**If you do care** about the old history of `staging`, then things get more fun:

```
git checkout staging        # First, merge beta into staging so we have
git merge -s theirs beta    # a merge commit to work with.

git checkout beta           # Then, flip back to beta's version of the files

git reset --soft staging    # Then we go back to the merge commit SHA, but keep 
                            # the actual files and index as they were in beta

git commit --amend          # Finally, update the merge commit to match the
                            # files and index as they were in beta.
```

Comment: This would delete unwanted files that were recently created on Staging?

Comment: @Trip Since it resets the index back to exactly what was in `beta`, anything that wasn't in beta should get deleted as far as Git is concerned.

Comment: Unfortunately `git merge -s theirs` isn't available in newer versions of Git, so this won't work exactly as written.

Comment: If you have a newer version of git use 'git merge -X theirs' instead of 'git merge -s theirs'.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you just rename it in case you change your mind.

```
git branch -m staging staging_oops
git checkout beta
git branch staging
```

If you really can't stand having that extra branch around:

```
git branch -D staging_oops
```

Answer (score 0):

If the history of staging is not going to be an issue, you can simply do this.

```
git checkout staging 
git reset --hard beta
```

Just remember the history of staging will be gone after the above command and 
***staging*** will have the work of your ***beta*** branch.