# Copy all files from master to another branch in git

Tags: git

I simply need to copy all files in the `master` branch to `production` branch and generate minified code etc there and check it in `production`.

I don't want to merge but only copy the files.

I tried to search in Google but I'm confused.

I'm following this crude method:

```
#currently I'm in master branch in current directory
rm -rf /tmp/production
cp -r . /tmp/production
rm -rf /tmp/production/.git
git checkout production
cp -r /tmp/production/* .
```

**Is there any single line command for this?**

Answer (score 0):

You could reuse a method from "[How can I overwrite, not merge, one remote branch into another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16171936/6309)"

```
git checkout production     # First, merge master into production so we have
git merge -s theirs master  # a merge commit to work with.

git checkout master         # Then, flip back to master's version of the files

git reset --soft production # Then we go back to the merge commit SHA, but keep 
                            # the actual files and index as they were in master

git commit --amend          # Finally, update the merge commit to match the
                            # files and index as they were in master.
```

It is not one line, but it does record the fact that `master` override `production` content.

Answer (score -2):

The easily thing you can do is when you create your branch production, you will positioned to master then you can push origin production.

Example:

```
git checkout -b production //to create branch production
git checkout master // to be positioned on the master 
git push origin production
```